# Why Visual Studio 2017 don't remove red line under errors after making them correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem working in visual studio 2017. The problem is, that When I correct an error, Visual Studio won't remove that error until I build the application. For example in the snippet below

```
public ActionResult Profile(PModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {     
     }         
}
```

It shows me a red line with a message that this method should return a value, and when I change it by adding `return View(model);` it still shows me that error. This problem is there for all another errors, but when I click build, it will successfully build and the red line will disappear.

Comment: You need to use `await` somewhere inside the method when declaring method with `async`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are trying? Of course the method is not `void` or `Task` so it has to return something. Can you add your alternative code?

Comment: Are you sure it's still indicating the *same* error?

Comment: @nondestructive: The method is `async` so `Task<ActionResult>` means you have to return an `ActinResult`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: You can and you should await, but you don't need to. The code will still compile (though with a warning).

Comment: if the method is marked as `async`, you don't have to return a specific type. Additionally, you're not forced to use `await`. No use in spreading misinformation in the comments.

Comment: No No. I don't have problem in writing action , i have Problem with vs .it don't remve red line under errors after i make correct them.my application run without any error when i click run and it will build successfully.

Comment: It might just be a misbehaving IntelliSense remembering old stuff. Happens all the time.

Comment: Did You try restart VS? Also try to remove .vs folder. I had similar issue on 2017.3 version.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah, turns out I _did_ misread the code (and deleted my question when I realised). Not exactly "spreading misinformation".

Comment: Background compilation can lag behind a little. Depends on how fast your comp is, if/when packages are loaded, plugins etc.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `async Task<ActionResult>` requires return type - so OP's code is already correct when he using `return View(model)`. Check `Error List` inside the VS (it should be no errors right now), probably Intellisense still unaware for the last change in few moments.

Comment: Are u using Resharper? And are u using .NET Standard Assemblies and normal .NET Assemblies mixed? If the answere is yes to all these Questions, its a known bug in resharper and will be fixed in a future update.